# Taking out exponent on logarithm in definite integral producing different answers

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

I was trying to find the following indefinite integral:
$$\int \frac{\ln(x)^2}{x}\,dx$$
Using u-substitution, I was getting two different answers based on if I took the exponent on the natural log out of the integral:

**Taking it out**
$$2 \int \frac{\ln(x)}{x}\,dx$$
$$u=\ln(x)$$
$$du=\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$
$$\Rightarrow 2\int u \, du=2\,\Big(\frac{u^2}{2}\Big)+c$$
$$\boldsymbol{=2\ln(x)+c}$$

**Not taken out**
$$\int \frac{\ln(x)^2}{x}\,dx=\int u^2\,du=\frac{1}{3}\,u^3+c$$
$$=\boldsymbol{\ln(x)+c}$$

Cannot quite figure out why I'm getting two different answers. Maybe it has to do with something I haven't yet learnt in class. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: please note $(\ln(x))^2$ is not the same as $\ln(x^2)=2\ln (x)$. I haven't read carefully but this could certainly be the source of your error

Comment: Ah I see. That was my mistake. Thank you for you answer!

Comment: The solution is  $\dfrac{ln(x)^3}{3}$.

Comment: the integrals you are computing are not definite

Answer (score 1):

Both are wrong.  The first fails because $\ln(x)^2 \neq 2 \ln(x)$.  Then when you backsubstituted you lost the square on $u$.  The second fails because you lost the square of the log.  You put it back in in the $\int u^2$, but then when you backsubstituted you lost the cube.  $u^3=(\ln (x))^3$  The correct answer is $\frac 13(\ln(x))^3+c$

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thank you for your answer! Filled a hole in my math knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int \Big(\! \ln x\Big)^2 \left( \frac {dx} x \right) = \int u^2 \, du. $$ $$\text{Note that } \ln(x^2) = 2\ln x \text{ but } \left( \ln x\right)^2 \ne 2\ln x.$$